# Desktop Notification JS workS on Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to develop a desktop notification JS in my customer application. The code works fine on firefox but not on Chrome.
 I'm changing  the notification permission to allow on settings -> Advanced -> Content Settings -> Notifications -> Allow/Deny but still not working.

this is my code :

notifyMe: function () {

```
     if (!("Notification" in window)) {

       alert("Ce navigateur ne supporte pas les notifications desktop");

     }

     else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {

      Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

         if(!('permission' in Notification)) {

           Notification.permission = permission;

         }

         if (permission === "granted") {

          var notification = new Notification("Notify ")

         }

       });

     }
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Works on my chrome 71.0.3578.98  with latest OSX

Answer (score 0):

You can activate it on Chrome by clicking on the lock inside the URL bar, on the left.

I tried in Firefox and it work, pls consider this Chrome behaviour:

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6451284559265792

It's no longer possible to ask for permission from a cross-origin iframe.